# Torchtext with Pytorch v1.10?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

Seems that Pytorch v1.10 is released, link here: https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.10-released/

I have a program with dependencies in Torchtext, and I run into this compatibility issue:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.10.0+cu111 requires torch==1.9.0, but you have torch 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
torchtext 0.10.0 requires torch==1.9.0, but you have torch 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

I want to use Pytorch v1.10 because of the label smoothing in `cross_entropy_loss`, would there be any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `torchtext 0.11.0` that compatible with `torch 1.10.0`